# Template that allows full screen image in android auto app?

Tags: android-auto

I am trying to make an Android Auto app that displays an image full-screen or at least 80% of the screen.  I can use the PaneTemplate to get mostly a split screen with text and an image but not what I am looking for.  Of course maps / nav can use most of the screen but not any other template I can see.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have currently templates to do that. PaneTemplate was something I would play but it's like playing with hacks.

I suggest reporting this at official issue tracker as "feature request" (Googlers are really reading that)